# Transparent GeometryModel3D

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I need to create a transparent GeometryModel3D.
Like this:
[image: Like this:]

I tried this code:

```
var m = new Model3DGroup();
var panelsGeometry = MyMeshGeometry3D;
        Brush br = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        br.Opacity = 0.5;
        m.Children.Add(new GeometryModel3D(panelsGeometry, new DiffuseMaterial(br)) { BackMaterial= new DiffuseMaterial(br) });
```

But as a result I get this:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the opacity just mixes the colour with the default appearance but does not affect the opacity of the polygons...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a transparent image with an `ImageBrush`, one pixel would be enough but you will need to set [`TextureCoordinates`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.meshgeometry3d.texturecoordinates.aspx) on the mesh object.

Comment: Could you give an example of this? I can not understand

Comment: @user1159999: Just create a `png` image wih a pixel that has the desired colour but at the transparency you want, make an ImageBrush from it, make a material from that, assign it to the properties. For the coordinates you probably can use something simple like `"0 1  1 1  0 0  1 0"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use TextureCoordinates and you wil have to order the sides to be drawn from back to front so they blend correctly. WPF doesn´t do this.

See [this article](http://www.ericsink.com/wpf3d/2_Transparency.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your box mesh geometry contains 24 points.  If your box contains the minimum number of points (8), then the behind faces won't be rendered.

For example, see [here](http://kindohm.com/blog/2007/04/30/use-of-normals-in-wpf-3d.html).

You can download the Normals3D.zip and change the brush opacity of the full mesh boxes to get the desired effect.